# Estimating the Capacity of Charged Used Li-ion Cells:

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I acquired 6 used li-ion cells 1 year ago.  Since I wanted to know for certain how well the cells would hold a charge after 1 year, I conducted an experiment.  I recently tested the cells.  Below is some data related to my testing:

**Charger info:**
 Voc = 5.25 (Open circuit Voltage--no cell in charger)
Imax = .68A (max charge current=680mA--no cell in charger)

**Cell Info:**

```
Manuf:  Panasonic
   Id:  CGR18650CE
    V:  3.6 (nominal)
  mAh:  2150 (typical capacity when fully charged)
+Chrg:  CC=1.43A (max), 4.2V (max)     // "+Chrg"=Charging
-Chrg:  CC=2.04A (max), cut-off @ 3V   // "-Chrg"=Discharging
```

**Notes:**
- All cells were charged at a CC=.68A to a CV=4.2V.  Charging was cutoff when the charge current reached .01A@4.2V
- The resting V of all cells after 24 hrs was at least 4.05V.

**Here are the cell measurements after 1 year of resting:**

```
Cell V___ A___ VA(W)  Est mAh (i.e. VA/3.6*1000)
1    4.16 3.29 13.67  3802
2    4.01 3.23 12.95  3598
3    3.95 3.18 12.56  3489
4    3.85 3.09 11.90  3305
5    3.95 3.17 12.52  3478
6    3.77 2.95 11.12  3089
```

The multimeter was verified to be operating properly using a bench power supply.

We can see from the data that some cells held their charge better than other cells. My question is, how can the cells have such a high capacity when the datasheet indicates their capacity is 2150mAh? I know the cells are at least 5 years old.  I also realize that my estimated mAh capacity is not based on actual discharge tests, but is there some other way of estimating the capacity of such cells using a multimeter & a bit of math?

Comment: Was your voltage reading off-load?  What load did you have on to measure the current?

Comment: Yes, the Voltage reading was terminal voltage read with just a Voltmeter.

Comment: You don't explain very well how you estimated the cell capacity. Obviously, the estimates are totally wrong, which is not surprising because you have not taken any data which would allow an estimate. Connect the cells to some a constant current load, or if you don't have one, a lamp or resistor and discharge them and record voltage and current at as many intervals as you can. You can stop the discharge at, say, 3V. You should aim for a current of around 500 mA or so, or if you are in a hurry, just do it at 1A (approximately).

Comment: The load for the test was provided by the Ammeter.

Comment: Did you short the cells with the multimeter in current measurement setting ???

Comment: No.  I did not short any cells together.  I merely measured each cell using the Ammeter function of my multimeter (meter+ to cell+ and meter- to cell-).  What that effectively does is put a load on the cell to test it's current output.

Comment: OK good, never short Li-Ion cells ! But then the Ammeter is not the load, there was no load, the cell was being charged. You measured the charging current.

Comment: No, I measured cell discharging current.  The Ammeter provides an internal load & the cell discharges into/through that load.  The cell is not connected to anything except the Ammeter at the time of testing.

Comment: @zeffur, what ammeter are you using, and what's the value of its internal load?  Most ammeters I'm familiar with do NOT have an internal load, and are designed to be connected in series with a circuit that includes a load already.  If you simply touch both battery terminals with a standard multimeter in current mode, you would indeed be shorting out the battery, since (usually) the meter doesn't add any appreciable resistance in current mode.

Comment: @Nate Strickland, I do not know the internal resistance of the ammeter.  If the cell was shorted through the ammeter, then whatever the meter showed was the max discharge current from each cell--based on the internal resistance of each cell.

Comment: In that case, your power estimate makes no sense, because you're multiplying voltage and current from two different states -- open circuit voltage, and short circuit current.  To actually measure stored power, you need to measure both voltage and current together, and integrate over the whole discharge curve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the point where you get from the cell voltage to the capacity. What you need to do is to discharge the cell with a constant current and measure the time until 2.7V is reached. This is done best with a electrical load or 4 quadrant source.

Comment: Volts x Amps = Watts.  Wh/nominal V = Ah (I noted that in the "Est mAh (i.e. VA/3.6*1000)" column heading for the data that I provided.  I know it is necessary to perform a proper discharge test to get an accurate capacity for an energy cell--that's not the point of the question that I asked--which is "...is there some other way of estimating the capacity of such cells using a multimeter & a bit of math?"

Comment: The answer is no. The momentary cell voltage does not tell you much. On a worn cell the "full" voltage is also 4.1V but it will drop very fast once you draw current. On a good cell the voltage will remain at 3.8V for a long time and then decline sharply as the battery becomes empty.

Comment: I agree that V is not the only important factor to consider when trying to determine the stored energy in a cell.  By looking at my data, you will see that I also measured the output of each cell using the internal resistance of the Ammeter.  From that I calculated/estimated Wh.  From that figure & the nominal V of the cell, I estimated available capacity.

Comment: Now, I know that number is not correct, however, it should be somewhat useful as it provides a relative difference from cell to cell (i.e. stronger cells have higher Wh & est. mAh & weaker less of each)...  Now the question is--can my method be correlated to some approximate energy capacity of a cell?  Finding a reasonably accurate method to determine energy capacity of a used cell with V and A measurements & a bit of math. Or, if someone else has another method, I'd certainly like to consider it.

Comment: Since the cell voltage is not linear with the capacity I see no feasible way to do a proper estimation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot estimate battery capacity quickly and accurately with a multimeter.  Measuring battery capacity is complex, and the most accurate methods require a full discharge cycle (and even these aren't perfect).  Otherwise, you need techniques like coulomb counting during charge and discharge, or look at the battery's response in the frequency domain to AC pulses.  There are specialized ICs built for these purposes.

For more info on estimating capacity and state-of-charge, see here:
https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_capacity

and for info on how one IC manufacturer does it, see here:
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/partners-and-technology/design-technology/modelgauge-battery-fuel-gauge-technology.html

As to why your back-of-the-envelope method didn't work, to measure power from the battery you need to multiply voltage provided and current being drawn *at the same time*.  The open-circuit voltages you see will immediately drop when you apply a load, and in general, for most of the discharge cycle, the voltage will be about 3.6V, so multiplying current draw by the voltage you see now will be an overestimate.  And multiplying that by a burst of short-circuit current won't tell you anything meaningful about capacity.

Answer (score 0):

To measure cell capacity accurately you should charge a cell to a specified voltage, for example 4.1 or 4.2 Volts.
Then DISCHARGE the cell with a constant current, for example 1 A, until the unloaded voltage (when no current flows) has reached 3.6 V (for example).

It is also not completely clear to me if you assumed that the charging current is constant. Because it should not be ! A proper Li-Ion charger will charge with a lower current when the cell's voltage is quite low and when it is nearly full. Only when the cell is around 40 % - 80 % full the charge current should be at it's maximum value.

You measured the charging of the cells which is not a 100% efficient process, some of the energy will be converterted into heat. This can explain why the measured capacity appears higher. The cell probably did not absorb all the mAhrs.

Comment: Does your response answer the question "...is there some other way of estimating the capacity of such cells using a multimeter & a bit of math?"  I charged the cells 1 year ago & allowed them to rest for 1 year.  The measurements are recent & they were obtained using a multimeter (Voltmeter & Ammeter).

Comment: What I explained is rougly the procedure that a battery manufacturer would use to measure the capacity of a cell. You followed a different procedure so the result cannot be compared. No you cannot repeat this procedure using a multimeter, you need a programmable load that can draw a constant current. You could use a resistive load (like 4 ohms) and every minute write down the voltage until the cell is 3.6 V then you would need to integrate the currents over time. That is complicated so that is why constant current discharging is used.

Comment: I agree with you & I was already aware of how a manuf. conducts such testing using a test setup that does exactly as you described.  My question is more along the lines of how a person with a multimeter using the Voltmeter & Ammeter might be able to get a reasonable approximation of the capacity of a cell after they have charged it.  The Ammeter uses a constant resistance.  I use my V & A measurements & a bit of math to derive the other data in the table.  As you can see & probably calculate, the max est mAh rating is 3802 which is ~1.77 times greater than the rating provided by the manuf.

Comment: Which also means the manuf. capacity is 1/that number or ~56.5% of the calculation that I show.  So, perhaps a better way of using such a simple test is to take the readings, do the math, & multiple the est mAh rating by 56.5%?

Comment: I would only take that number (using your method) as an indication of the capacity. To see if a cell is still good or that it has worn out. For an accurate capacity measurement it is not a good method. And for one cell it might be 1.77 but for another type or older cell it might be 1.60 or 1.90. Also a 4 year old cell might not have the manufacturer specified capacity of 2150 mAh anymore, it could be 1500 mAh for example due to wear of the cell.

Comment: I am aware that it is not an accurate capacity determination method.  The purpose of trying to define a simpler cell capacity test is that I don't want to fully charge & then discharge to cutoff, 100s of 18650 cells.  I suppose the best way to test my method is to test it on a NEW cell & then compare that to how it works on older cells to see if there is a relatively accurate capacity correlation that can be observed using the method that I have described.  I guess I was hoping someone here would have much more experience with this kind of thing & know of & share such a method here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with experience or lack thereof. In my opinion, what  you want is simply impossible, there is no method to measure this quickly. If you have 100s of cells then it is possible they come from different batches and have different leakage. The cells with more leakage will accept more charge (because they are more empty) but that does not mean they have a higher storage capacity.

Comment: re: "leakage"...  It appears to me that you may think that I am using some kind of Ah counter when I charge cells to get the estimate that I have made.  I do not have such a device.  I am charging single cells until they are 4.2V in circuit & charge current is @ .01A--then I stop the charge, let the cell rest 24 hrs, test the V & A using a multimeter & estimate (ie calculate) the Wh & mAh of the cell based on the values shown by the multimeter.

Comment: Yes, I thought you had a charger that keeps track of the amount of charge  that is pumped into the cell. OK but then the Voltage and and current that you measure mean nothing. That measurement says absolutely nothing about the capacity of the cell. In order to determine a "true" capacity chemical reactions need to take place in the cells, that only happens when you discharge them and that takes time. No shortcuts can be taken here I'm afraid.

Comment: The measurements allow us to see the 'output capacity' of the cells & to calc the output power of each cell, but that limited set of data isn't enough info for us to determine the available energy capacity of each used cell. To get that I would have to continue to discharge them (ideally with a varying load to maintain a constant discharge current) & record the V&A until they each arrived at the cutoff Voltages, then integrate the recorded data to determine the discharge capacity of each cell.

Comment: Since the current data does allow us to compare the output power of each cell,  I'm going compare the output of a new cell to that data set.  Perhaps I can glean something useful from that comparison.  I suppose the only other practical thing that I can do with my current tools is to discharge a new cell and the best & worst used cells through a given load to determine how much time each cell will service the load until the 3V cutoff limit is reached.  Discharge time for a given load is useful capacity information.

Comment: @zeffur - I have tried, and have not been able to find a way to get an even approximate capacity with only a multimeter.  At best I think that you may be able to get a relative strength of a battery.  I tried and tried but in the end I bought the imax b6 charger/discharge which will give you a very accurate capacity.  The best part is that the imax b6 is relatively inexpensive, some places as low as $30-40,

Comment: @Filek - The difficult thing about estimating available energy in a cell without a meter like the Imax B6 is you can never know unless you test a cell for how long it will remain in it's relatively flat discharge curve when a variable resistance is used to maintain a constant current discharge.  As stated earlier, I was hoping to discover a method to approximate available capacity without having to fully discharge hundreds of 18650 cells---looks like that might just be wishful thinking at this point.

Comment: @zelfur - yes, your question was about finding an accurate way of measuring Lion capacity with just a multimeter and the answer must be no.  Also, in your measurments, you measured watts, not watt-hours if I understand your experiment correctly.  If that is the case, your estimate if capacity has no meaning at all.  Also, when measuring the amps, was the voltage being measured simultaneously, or was the voltage measured first and then amps?  Because when you draw 2-3 amps from an 18650, the voltage will drop significantly while providing the amps, and that is the voltage you want to measure.

Comment: I wish there was a way to use the multimeter only, but the more I think about it, the more I realize that the readings tell us very little about capacity.  I just don't see a way around the old fashioned discharge or partial discharge to estimate capacity.

Comment: Good points, Filek.  Thx for your comments.